# Light layer in blender

Tags: lighting, render-layers, layers, light-groups

So i was editing light on this road and suddenly new light layer wont work. Even tho the old light layer behind still working. Can someone help?
[image]

Comment: hello, what do you mean by "light layer"? Are you talking about the light areas? You can use a maximum of 128 lights in Eevee, is it your problem here?

Comment: thanks bro
sorry for my bad english

Comment: No problem, does the number of lights explain your problem? If not, please share your file